# Python syntax -> bool

Tags: python

I have a lot of Matlab experience but trying to learn Python syntax from `Leetcode` challenges. What does the `-> bool` mean in the method below?

```
def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
    vals = []
    current_node = head
    while current_node is not None:
        vals.append(current_node.val)
        current_node = current_node.next
    return vals == vals[::-1]
```

Here's the entire code:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
        vals = []
        current_node = head
        while current_node is not None:
            vals.append(current_node.val)
            current_node = current_node.next
        return vals == vals[::-1]
isPalindrome(head)
```

Comment: It's a [type-hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Comment: It indicates (but does not enforce) that the function returns a `bool` value

Comment: Thanks, so it's just a comment? And do you have any ideas why this is giving me a syntax error? Pasted the entire code in my original post

Comment: It's a [function annotation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-function-annotation), intended to be interpreted as a type hint by 3rd-party tools like `mypy`.

Comment: What is the exact error? Function annotations aren't part of Python 2, and your code has additional indentation problems.

Comment: The error is invalid syntax line 6

Comment: The last line `isPalindrome(head)` seems like it would result in a NameError for at least one reason.

Answer (score 1):

The `-> bool` just tells that `isPalindrome()` returns a boolean, but it doesn't force the function to return a boolean.

Look at PEP 3107: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

And PEP 484: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/
It states:

> Function annotations are nothing more than a way of associating arbitrary Python expressions with various parts of a function at compile-time.

This is called function annotation.

You could also use `mypy` to do type checking on your code.

> Mypy is an optional static type checker for Python that aims to
> combine the benefits of dynamic (or “duck”) typing and static typing.

Answer (score 1):

It is called a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). Basically, it gives you hints as to what type the function will return.

In your code, `-> bool` hints that `isPalindrome()` returns a boolean value.

Comment: You could also mention `Mypy` is a static type checker for Python for this post.